# adobe phonegap build "unable to clone/checkout repository" despite public repo

Tags: android, adobe, phonegap-build, cloud9-ide, git-clone

I have an app that I was previously able to use adobe PGB to build an .apk for but after I either got a white screen or "initializing" screen on my android that lasted forever I decided to make some changes to the config.xml file as well as comment out any plugins (i.e. cordova.js) since pgb assures me it will inject them as necessary.

Now I get this error on adobe PGB before even building, when trying to pull latest/update code from my feature branch with these changes : "unable to clone/checkout repository". This error has come up only on those branches I have made the changes on (i.e. "feature-phonegap" and later, "develop"). I was able to point adobe PGB to my git repo, specifically develop, prior to the changes to the config file and commenting out plugins and PGB would build it but then I would have the same app that worked on the web (developed on cloud9's IDE) but not on my android device (although it works via Ionic View).

I have checked that my git repo is public and I am concerned that because I didn't allow adobe PGB read/write permissions at some point and access to the git repo that that is causing the issue? I am very reluctant to allow anyone outside of those working on this project to have write permissions to the git and subsequently the code. Maybe that's the oversight and nothing to worry about?

I hope there is a solution where I can continue to use adobe PGB so I can start debugging the app as I see how it behaves on android devices. Please let me know of any successes that people have had using pgb and ways that anyone else has overcome this.

All suggestions and questions are welcome. Thank you.